# Refactoring Stores from initializers to services

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am in the process of migrating my app form `Ember.1.12` to `Ember.1.13.8`

I recently opened this issue: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3719 because my store namespace was no longer applied when transitioning from `RESTAdapter` to `JSONAPIAdapter`

I have custom stores that are loaded with initializers:

**Ember1.12 Code**

```
initialize = (container, app) ->

  config = container.lookup('config:main')
  store = DS.Store.extend
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.extend
      namespace: 'v1/crm'
      auth: container.lookup('auth-manager:main')
      headers: (->
        'Authorization': @get('auth.token')
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        'Accept': 'application/json-ember'
      ).property('auth.token')
  app.register 'crm-provisioning:main', store
  app.inject 'route', 'crm-provisioning', 'crm-provisioning:main'
  app.inject 'controller', 'crm-provisioning', 'crm-provisioning:main'
  app.inject 'component', 'crm-provisioning', 'crm-provisioning:main'

CrmProvisioningInitializer =
  name: 'crm-provisioning'
  after: ['config', 'auth-manager']
  initialize: initialize

`export {initialize}`
`export default CrmProvisioningInitializer`
```

Now, for Ember 1.13 it was mentioned in the issue I opened, that I should be using stores as services: http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_custom-stores

I am unsure about how to refactor that code.

- How will I access the other initializers that I was previously looking up through the container?
- Does it mean I need to move all my initializers to services? For example the config initializer
- Is there an easy way to inject the services in all routes,controllers, and components? Apparently this can be done through instance initializers(Which I am really confused about), but how does this fit with stores as services?